# Neo4j embedded not shown in Server

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm currently fiddling with Neo4j. For starters I want to create some Nodes and Relations and display them in the Server Web Interface.

I copy & pasted code snippets from here: http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded-setup

When I create the data in my code I am able to read it in the next iteration (see //debug Method). So it was saved (right?). But I cannot view the data within the Neo4j Servers Web-Viewer. I re-configured the Servers DB to my embedded database and it shows the right database-name.

So why can't I see my data? Thanks in advance.

My Code looks as follows:

```
    public class TestApp2 {

    private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
    {
        KNOWS
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("/home/foo/workspace/Neo4JConnector/db3.db");
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(file);
        registerShutdownHook( graphDb );

        try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
        {
            checkForNode(graphDb);

            Node firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
            firstNode.setProperty( "message", "Hello, " );
            Node secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
            secondNode.setProperty( "message", "World!" );
            Relationship relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS );
            relationship.setProperty( "message", "brave Neo4j " );

            System.out.print( firstNode.getProperty( "message" ) );
            System.out.print( relationship.getProperty( "message" ) );
            System.out.println( secondNode.getProperty( "message" ) );
            tx.success();
            tx.close();
        }

        System.out.println("got it! Going to sleep now...");
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }

    // debug
    private static void checkForNode(GraphDatabaseService graphDb)
    {
        Node node = null;
        try
        {
            node = graphDb.getNodeById(0);
        }
        catch (NotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("initial run");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Node found: "+node.getProperty("message"));
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

My Neo4j-Config points to the same folder:

```
dbms.active_database=/home/foo/workspace/Neo4JConnector/db2.db
```

Comment: You mean that checkForNode not show info for node with ID === 0?

Comment: Since the IDs are incremental starting from 0, the second run should find a Node with this id. And it does. But there's no data visible in the web viewer.If there's no solution to this I would have to live with using the Cypher Driver as shown in this example https://neo4j.com/developer/java/#neo4j-java-driver